# Current date - Go to next Thursday - PHP

Tags: php, date

This is my code for get the current date in french (I'm french) and the current time :

```
<?php

setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra');

// FIX date & time email
    $date_line = strftime("%A %d %B");
    $time_line = date('H:i:s');

?>
```

With this result, I want to find a method for : How to get date of the Thursday since the current date please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [relative date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). In this case 'next Thursday'. Here's a basic example:

```
$time_line = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next Thursday'));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/638929)

Comment: Serious question, is there a difference between "next Thursday" and "this Thursday"

Comment: Decided to _actually test_ my own question. Appears the main (only perhaps) difference is if today was the day being search for, so if it was "this friday" today would be returned as opposed to next week. Which kind of makes sense logically, but not always expected in English.

Comment: That makes perfect sense logically speaking. But it is easy to see how this can be considered an unexpected result as well.